# Why in this proof does $g$ (an element of a group) and $g^r=e$ imply $r=0$.

Tags: group-theory

In my group theory course, we have been given the following theorem:
Let $G$ be a group and $g \in G$ with $\vert g \vert = n$. Then, $g^k=e$ if and only if $n \vert k$. The proof supplied by my instructors for the necessary condition (and the accompanying explanation) is troubling me.

Their proof proceeds as follows:

$g^k = e$, and $k = qn + r; 0 \leq r < n$.

Then
$g^k = g^{qn+r} = g^{qn}g^{r} = e$. This implies that either $g^{qn} = e$ or $g^r=e$.

My question is: how in this case does $g^r = e$ imply that $r=0$? This is not true in general - so if their deduction is correct then what condition  makes $g^r = e$ imply that $r=0$?

I have posted a screenshot from the memo we were sent for this problem: [image]

Comment: "This implies that either $g^{qn}=e$ or $g^r=e$." This is very very false! What is true though is that $g^{qn}=(g^n)^q=e^q=e$. Hence $g^r=e$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|g|=n$ means that $n$ is the smallest integer such that $g^n=e$. If $0\leq r<n$ and satisfies $g^r=0$, then $r$ must be $0$

Comment: False. You need the extra assumption that $r < n$. $g^{kn} = 0$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. EDIT: Your edit came at the same time.

Comment: I forgot to write $r<n$, I guess it's correct now

Comment: I see how this theorem would follow given that definition of the order of an element. However, in our course, the order of an element $a$ is defined as the order of the cyclic group generated by $a$. That is, $\vert a \vert = \vert <a> \vert $. Edit: this is a theorem (exercise) in Rotman

Comment: Isn't it equivalent? It's easy to prove that $|a|=n$ (my definition) if and only if $|<a>|=n$ (your definition)

Comment: @DanielLevin : it is exactly the same definition.The group $\langle g \rangle$ is the subgroup of $G$ constituted of the elements $g^k$ for any $k \in \mathbb N$. If $g^n = e$ then $g^{m+n} = g^m$, so any $g^k$ with $k\geq n$ is already met for some $k<n$. Hence, the cardinal of $\langle g \rangle$ is the number of element in $\{g^0,g^1,\dots,g^{m-1}\}$ where $m$ is the first (non-zero) integer such that $g^m=e$.

Comment: Exactly :) Thank you for your comments!

Comment: dlc and Pece, thank you for your answers :). It is (now) obvious why the two definitions are equivalent but I had just never seen the other one before.

Comment: Anytime, @DanielLevin

Answer (score 1):

Remember the definition of the order of an element in a group: it is the *smallest* positive integer $n$ such that $g^n=e$. So if $g^r=e$ and $0\leq r < n$, then we must have $r=0$ since it is smaller than $n$.

Comment: I have written it on the other comment, but this is not how the order of an element is defined in my course.

Comment: Well, if $g^r=e$ and $0< r <n$, then $|\langle g\rangle |=r$, which is a contradiction since $|\langle g\rangle |=n$. So we must have $r=0$.

Answer (score 0):

This implies that either gqn=e or gr=e...
Nope. This actually implies that in fact g^(qn) = (g^n)^q = e^q=e and hence in this case q^r = e. which is only possible if r = 0 since 0<=r < n